# AWS Endpoint Forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance (prod-123.abc123xyz456.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com).

I am migrating this server to a new account. When I do so the URL for the new RDS instance will be different (prod-123.qwe987rty654.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com).

I am told I can't migrate the abc123xyz456 part of the URL. Is there any way I can do some kind of forwarding from abc123xyz456 to qwe987rty654?

Alternately can I migrate abc123xyz456 as well?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot avoid changing the configuration that targets this database. If you want to keep this flexibility in future, you can create your own CNAME record with the RDS address as its value, but you would still need to update your applications to point at the new CNAME.

Answer (score 1):

As @arco44 points out it is always a good practice to use your own DNS entry pointing to an AWS DNS entry using a CNAME (Alias) record. More specific e.g. prddb.mycompany.com would point to prod-123.abc123xyz456.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com and your application uses prddb.mycompany.com.

Another approach is with VPC peering you can access the DB DNS in your old account from the application in your new account.

If your requirement is that the DB also has to be migrated to the new account then you have to bite the sour apple and migrate the data of your RDS instance from the old account to the new account.